# Pythonengine Matlab cannot find attributes like 'find_matlab'

Tags: python, python-2.7, matlab, virtualenv, attributeerror

I am running python 2.7 and matlab2015a from a virtual environment. Both matlab and python are properly in the path (I can start them from terminal). But, whenever I do this:

```
python
from matlab.engine import pythonengine
pythonengine.find_matlab()
```

I get this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'find_matlab'
```

I get similar errors for all other functions in `__init__.py` in my /lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine.

I have installed the pythonengine using the instructions in https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/install-the-matlab-engine-for-python.html from my virtualenvironment.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `find_matlab()` is a function of matlab.engine, not matlab.engine.pythonengine. Try:

```
python
import matlab.engine
matlab.engine.find_matlab()
```

Comment: Thank you! Matlabfuture.py also gives an AttributeError when trying to pythonengine.createMATLABAsync(tokens). Changing this to matlab.engine instead of pythonengine gives the same AttributeError. Do you have an idea of which module I should be using?

Comment: `File <virtualenv>/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matlab/engine/matlabfuture.py", line 48, in __init__
    self._future = matlab.engine.createMATLABAsync(tokens)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'createMATLABAsync'
Exception AttributeError: "'MatlabFuture' object has no attribute '_future'" in <bound method MatlabFuture.__del__ of <matlab.engine.matlabfuture.MatlabFuture object at 0x10649b850>> ignored
Exception AttributeError: "FutureResult instance has no attribute '_FutureResult__future'"`

Comment: Is this happening when running the only 3 lines above?